# How to implement an Action on Item Click in Order to show the result in CardView of RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, cardview

I am very new to Android programming. I can't find a solution for my current problem which I've been trying to solve for days.

I want to click on item of populated Array List and get the position i.e. the searched word result in Cardview (neither ItemClickListener nor OnSuggestionListener did work here. Here is my code of MainActivity and I would be very thankful if somebody could help me out:

````
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SearchAdapter adapter;

    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
    Database database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //init View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

        database = new Database(this);

        materialSearchBar.setHint("Search");
        materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
        loadSuggestList();
        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener (new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String search : suggestList) {
                    if (search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                        suggest.add(search);
                }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener (new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                if (!enabled)
                    adapter = new SearchAdapter(getBaseContext(), database.getLughats());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                startSearch(text.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
            }

        });

        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getLughats());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void startSearch(String text) {
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getLughatByWort(text));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void loadSuggestList() {
        suggestList = database.getWorts();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    }
}```

Let me know if I should post here also my AdapterCode for the ViewHolder.

Thank you for your help in advance!
````

Comment: What result to you want to show on item clicked? Where is the adapter code?

Comment: I want to get the result as described above by clicking or seleting of the item to be showed in cardview. Currently I have to activate the search over the keyboard i.e. with the method setOnSearchActionListener. But I would have the search to be activated by clicking the item or selecting it.

Comment: Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here ist my AdapterCode:

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    RecyclerItemClick itemClickListener;
    public TextView wort, praeteritum, partizip2, artikelGrammatik, uebersetzung1, uebersetzung2;
    public ImageButton button1, button2;


    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        wort = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wort);
        praeteritum = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.praeteritum);
        partizip2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.partizip2);
        artikelGrammatik = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.artikelGrammatik);
        uebersetzung1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.uebersetzung1);
        uebersetzung2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.uebersetzung2);

        button1 = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_id_1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_id_2);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(RecyclerItemClick ic) {
        this.itemClickListener = ic;
    }
}
        public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {

            private Context context;
            private List<Lughat> lughats;

            public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Lughat> lughats) {
                this.context = context;
                this.lughats = lughats;

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
                return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                holder.wort.setText(lughats.get(position).getWort());
                holder.praeteritum.setText(lughats.get(position).getPraeteritum());
                holder.partizip2.setText(lughats.get(position).getPartizip2());
                holder.artikelGrammatik.setText(lughats.get(position).getArtikelGrammatik());
                holder.uebersetzung1.setText(lughats.get(position).getUebersetzung1());
                holder.uebersetzung2.setText(lughats.get(position).getUebersetzung2());

                CharSequence praet;
                praet = holder.praeteritum.getText();
                if (praet.length() == 0) {
                    holder.praeteritum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.praeteritum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                CharSequence part2;
                part2 = holder.partizip2.getText();
                if (part2.length() == 0) {
                    holder.partizip2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.partizip2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                CharSequence artGr;
                artGr = holder.artikelGrammatik.getText();
                if (artGr.length() == 0) {
                    holder.artikelGrammatik.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.artikelGrammatik.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                CharSequence ueb2;
                ueb2 = holder.uebersetzung2.getText();
                if (ueb2.length() == 0) {
                    holder.uebersetzung2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.uebersetzung2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new ToastMaker(context.getApplicationContext()));
                holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new ToastMaker(context.getApplicationContext()));

                holder.setItemClickListener(new RecyclerItemClick() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Begriff", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return lughats.size();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do it also with OnClickListener it does not work too, it does not call the method startSearch.

```
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CharSequence text = materialSearchBar.getText();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startSearch(text.toString());
            }
```